# How to make a sprite jump only once in IOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a project in iOS where i have sprites rolling towards a "player" sprite and the goal is for the sprite to jump over the projectiles without touching them. I created a function for him to jump, yet i need him to only jump once when he leaves the ground rather than continuously. I need help on creating code that lets the sprite leave the ground when jumps, but it only jumps again after it touches the ground.

Here is the code i currently have:

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let jumpUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 50, duration: 0.3)
    let fallBack = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -50, duration: 0.3)
    // making the player jump
    player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([jumpUp, fallBack]))

}
```

Comment: you need to understand the concept of states for your sprite. This can be done with an enum/Struct (Running_State, Jumping_State) `if(state == Jumping_State) { do code }`, or you can just create an implied state, `if( sprite.velocity.y != 0)` sprite is in a falling/jumping state.  Be careful with this though, because that means you can't walk diagnally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can do this easily by simply checking to see if the `player` node currently has a 'jump' action running on it.**

For example:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if player.actionForKey("jump") == nil { // check that there's no jump action running
        let jumpUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 50, duration: 0.3)
        let fallBack = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -50, duration: 0.3)

        player.runAction(SKAction.sequence([jumpUp, fallBack]), withKey:"jump")
    }
}
```

---

### Edit

It's also worth noting that if you're not changing any aspects of the actions, you could just create them once and reuse them in your `touchesBegan()`.

For example:

```
class MyScene : SKScene {

    let jumpUp = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 50, duration: 0.3)
    let fallBack = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: -50, duration: 0.3)
    var jumpAction = SKAction()

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        jumpAction = SKAction.sequence([jumpUp, fallBack])
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
        if player.actionForKey("jump") == nil {
            player.runAction(jumpAction, withKey:"jump")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: someone give this guy a trophy

Comment: i've been working on this for about a month and i couldn't figure it out

Comment: glad to be of help :) Also worth noting that if you don't change any aspects of the action, you could always create it once and then reuse it. I have edited my answer showing how to do this.